Auto increment project version in dockerfile
I have an application in java that is deployed inside a docker container, but every time I make a new release I have to manually update the version of the app in the docker file, is there any way to automate this by taking the version directly from the pom?
Here my dockerfile
FROM openjdk:17
COPY target/projectName-x.x.x.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]

obviously instead of x.x.x is the correct version number
and here the pom
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.5</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>
<groupId>com.groupName</groupId>
<artifactId>projectArtifactId</artifactId>
<version>x.x.x-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>projectName</name>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <image>
                    <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                </image>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>it.ivannotarstefano.ultimateserver.UltimateServerApplication</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


EDIT: SOLVED
I solved the problem with a * in the Dockerfile for replace the project version
FROM openjdk:17
COPY target/projectName-*.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]


Would you mind sharing a reduced version of your pom file? With the relevant information? Just to be sure we are not in a <version>${project.version}</version> case.

You could do COPY target/projectName-*.jar app.jar. Otherwise, you could use Spring Boot native Docker support rather than write a Dockerfile

you could use maven resource filtering in combination with maven copy resources to get your maven version into the dockerfile. Just make sure that you use it somewhere from the target folder in filtered form when you build the image.

There are couple of ways you can try,

If you are using gitlab ci/cd pipeline then, you can write below steps in you .gitlab-ci.yaml file,

.gitlab-ci.yaml
stages:
   - stage_1
   - stage_2
   - versioning
   - build
 variable:
    APP_VERSION: "1.0"
 versioning:
    stage: "versioning"
    script: 
      - if [! -f version.txt]; then echo "$APP_VERSION" > version.txt fi
      - APP_VERSION=$(echo "$APP_VERSION + 1.0" | bc)
      - echo "$APP_VERSION" > version.txt
  build:
    stage: "build"
    script: 
       - docker build --build-arg APP_VERSION="$APP_VERSION" -t projectName:"$APP_VERSION" .

But only two changes you have to do in you above dockerfile,
FROM openjdk:17
ARG APP_VERSION
COPY target/projectName-${APP_VERSION}.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]


If you are doing it locally you can create you own build.sh file and do below steps,
# check if version.txt file exist, otherwise create one and store initial version
   if [ ! -f version.txt]; then echo "1.0" > version.txt fi
# declare a variable to store current version
   CURRENT_VERSION=$(<version.txt)
# create a new version
   UPDATED_VERSION=$(echo "$CURRENT_VERSION + 1.0" | bc)
# write new version back to file
   echo "$UPDATED_VERSION" > version.txt
# then build docker image with new version
   docker build --build-arg APP_VERSION="$UPDATED_VERSION" -t projectName:"$UPDATED_VERSION" .



Hope this will resolve your issue

Look, this approach is not very good. Docker can't take something and put "variable" in it to reuse.
What you need is to retrieve as compile argument
FROM openjdk:17
ARG ARTIFACT_VERSION
COPY target/projectName-$ARTIFACT_VERSION.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]

When compiling, pass the version.
docker build --build-arg ARTIFACT_VERSION=1 .

You can retrieve the version with this command:
ARTIFACT_VERSION_FROM_POM=$(mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.2.0:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout)

all together
docker build --build-arg ARTIFACT_VERSION=$ARTIFACT_VERSION_FROM_POM .

Another option would be to set the artifact name to fixed.
Putting the lines in pom.xml:
   <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>${project.parent.artifactId}-fixed-version</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

